# How do I make make my notification use default application colours?

Tags: android, user-interface, notifications

I am following this [tutorial](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html) on notifications, however, my notification is greyed out.

I know there's remote views to style it, but this developers guide does not use it.

Here is an example of how my notification looks

[image: As you can see here, my notification is all grey. I just modified the text and icon in paint to hide business stuff]

Answer (score 0):

In your builder, use .setColor()
it requires a minimum api

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
    builder.setColor(Color.BLUE);
}
```